# Facebook api 'user_posts' permission

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Am using Facebook API for read the user posts from user Facebook account. In Facebook authentication page i have added 'user_posts' parameter in scope.

```
       $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' =>  email, user_posts'));
```

But when sign in into the Facebook its not asking the Facebook permission popup. When i add the 'email,user_friends' permissions to the scope, the Facebook permission window shown.Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: publish_stream is deprecated since many years, and you don´t need it for reading. don´t copy code that is several years old...

Comment: Sorry, Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely are you are not trying with an app admin. Without Login Review, most permissions only work for users with a role in the App. More about Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Btw, you should consider using a newer version of the PHP SDK, it looks like you are using a very old one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it from Facebook account of Developer/Admin of the particular Application.

For other users, the particular permission should be reviewed & approved by Facebook.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should use "publish_actions" instead of "publish stream" as the other user said, "publish_stream" is deprecated.

Comment: he wants to read the user posts, publish_actions is for posting and publish_stream is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question, I know that "publish_stream" is deprecated and "publish actions" is the one to use for posting as I use it myself.  My apologies.

Comment: That's fine.But i need to get the 'user_posts' permission. Here is my current permission list

{
   "data": [
      {
         "permission": "user_friends",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "email",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "public_profile",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "installed",
         "status": "granted"
      }
   ]
}